# Is it possible to get the table from a PDOStatement object?

Tags: php, database, pdo

Say I have a `PDOStatement` object generated via `PDO->query($query)`, is it possible to get the table it was executed on?

Something like this:

```
<?php
$statement = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `foo`;');
echo $statement->xyz;
// foo
```

I'm fully aware you can use `$query->getColumnMeta(0)['table']` to do it, but [as mentioned by the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php), it's not very safe. This needs to work across all PDO drivers.

Comment: Imagine there is a database without tables and a PDO driver exists for it. It then can not work across all PDO drivers. What now?

Comment: Fair enough, I guess. I'm going to use `getColumnMeta`, then extend the class in the cases it doesn't work in.

Comment: I'd say that's the best you can do. Inject compat layers per PDO driver type so that you can easily handle that for the different cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can retreive the name of the table using the PDOStatement that retrieves an associative array. The value ['name'] is the name of the table.

```
    $select = $conn_pdo->query('SELECT * FROM foo');
    $meta = $select->getColumnMeta(0);
    echo "Name of table: ".$meta['table'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the query string:

```
$statement->queryString
```

Remember that a SQL query may reference multiple tables, or no tables, so there is no "table it was executed on". You could use regular expressions on the query string to find the first table referenced for standard queries (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`), but that may not be perfect.

Alternatively, use models to access your data, and you'll always know which tables are accessed by the model definition.

Comment: I thought I should mention some context. This is for the underlying system that will enable models in [Scaffold](http://github.com/Scaffold/Scaffold).

Comment: I can't use the queryString, because not all PDO drivers are SQL based. For `SQL`, it will always be the `SELECT * FROM {table}` or `INSERT INTO {table}`.

Comment: Are there PDO drivers that don't use a query string at all? I would think you could check the query string regardless of whether it's SQL or something else. Of course, you would have to write different rules to test for different query languages.

AFAIK there is no way to ask PDO which tables/datasets/collections/etc were referenced by a query. Such functionality would need to be implemented in the database itself, and across all drivers, in order for it to be useful. (And it's not, which is why `getColumnMeta` is 'unsafe' - it's not available on all drivers).

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply store the string used in the query and use simple string manipulations to access the table?